# Create MySQL unique ID while inserting list eliments in a DB

Tags: mysql, sql, rss

I'm actually downloading feeds from a homepage and try to write them into a MySQL DB. The Feeds are published in RSS. Everything is working fine without the creation of the unique ID. So the Insert command must be wrong!

Here is my Code:

```
import feedparser
import urllib2
import cookielib
import MySQLdb
import time
import datetime
from cookielib import CookieJar
from urllib2 import urlopen

db = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost", # your host, usually localhost
                 user="root", # your username - SELECT * FROM mysql.user
                 passwd="****", # your password
                 db="sentiment_analysis") # name of the data base

cur = db.cursor()
cur.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS feeddata_lse")

sql = """CREATE TABLE feeddata_lse (LSE_ID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,PRIMARY KEY(LSE_ID),Unix_Timesstamp integer, III_Timestamp varchar(255), Source varchar(255), Title varchar(255), Text TEXT,  Link varchar(255), Epic varchar(255), CommentNr integer, Author varchar(255))"""
cur.execute(sql)

opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(CookieJar()))
opener.addheaders = [{'User-agent','Mozilla/5.0'}]

def feed_load(feed):
return [(time.time(),
         entry.published,
         'lse',
         entry.title,
         entry.summary,
         entry.link,
         (entry.link.split('?ShareTicker=')[1]).split('&post=')[0],
         entry.link.split('&post=')[1],
         entry.author)
        for entry
        in feedparser.parse(feed).entries]

def main():
FEED_URL = "http://www.lse.co.uk/chat/recent/"
feed = feed_load(FEED_URL)

print feed[1][1]

for item in feed:
    cur.execute("""INSERT INTO feeddata_lse VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)""",item)
db.commit()
```

If I delete the `LSE_ID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, PRIMARY KEY(LSE_ID)` out to the Insert statement everything works fine. My major problem with changing the insert-part is that a RSS feed contains a list of feeds and every feed is another list.

**Thank you for helping me.** Please explain you arguments with code examples because I am very unexperienced. If you have any questions feel free to ask!

Here is the error report:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Python27/MySQL_finalversion/rss_db_connection_mysql_v1.py", line 54, in <module>
main()
File "C:/Python27/MySQL_finalversion/rss_db_connection_mysql_v1.py", line 48, in main
cur.execute("""INSERT INTO feeddata_lse VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)""",item)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py", line 205, in execute
self.errorhandler(self, exc, value)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\connections.py", line 36, in defaulterrorhandler
raise errorclass, errorvalue
OperationalError: (1136, "Column count doesn't match value count at row 1")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `LSE_ID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, PRIMARY KEY(LSE_ID)` line occurs in the table creation statement, not the insert statement. If you remove a column from the table creation statement, but leave your INSERT statement unchanged, you will indeed get a "Column count doesn't match value" error because you're attempting to insert one more column than is defined on your table.

I think you'll find you actually want to keep that primary key. Rather than remove `LSE_ID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, PRIMARY KEY(LSE_ID)` from your table creation statement, maybe try explicitly naming the columns in your INSERT statement like so?

`INSERT INTO feeddata_lse(Unix_Timesstamp, III_Timestamp, Source, Title, Text, Link, Epic, CommentNr, Author) VALUES (%s,%s,` ...